# How can i remove this extra "*" from the end

Tags: python, loops

help me how can i remove that extra "*" at the end

```
num = int(input("Enter number :"))
factorial = 1
if num==0:
    print(" 1")
```

then i used else and started a loop

```
else:
    for i in range (1,num+1):
        factorial = factorial * i
        
        print(i,end="*")
    
    print ("\n=",factorial)
```

when run the code you can see the output  in which at last you can see that extra"*" symbol how can i remove only that extra "*" symbol.
As i don't have much reputation I can't use image to show you.

Comment: "As i don't have much reputation I can't use image to show you." If you write a program that `print`s some output, and you want to show us what happened, then copy and paste the output and format it like code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way can be to print `1` outside the loop, then change range condition to start from `2`. Then start by printing the asterisk `*` first, rather than at the end:

```
num = int(input("Enter number :"))
factorial = 1
if num==0:
    print(" 1")
else:
    print(1, end='')

    for i in range(2, num + 1):
        factorial = factorial * i

        print(end=f'*{i}')

    print("\n=", factorial)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but can you please explain me briefly how it works. because i got the desired output with this answer

Comment: So I meant to explain it at the top, but basically I print out `1` first. Then in the loop, I print asterisk `*` followed by each number. So `*2`, then `*3` and so on.

Comment: Well, try to follow the logic of the program. What does `f'*{i}'` do? What happens if you `print` with an `end` value, but no actual items to print? So, what is the result from `print(end=f'*{i}')`? What happens if you do that for every value except the first one? What happens if you put `1` before that?

Comment: The idea is that it's easier to do special handling the first time than it is to do special handling the last time.

Answer (score 0):

you can print "*" along side numbers but that should be less than the number of iterations

```
num = int(input("Enter number :"))
factorial = 1
if num==0:
    print(" 1")
else:
    for i in range (1,num+1):
        factorial = factorial * i
        print(i,end="")
        if(i<num):
            print("*",end="")
    
    print ("\n=",factorial)
```